# What is the difference for the Azure SQL database in different region(Server)?

Tags: sql-server, azure, cloud

I live in NZ and I am building the Azure Cloud SQL database now. There are so many locations I need to select. For example, what is the difference if I am choosing the Australia east server or Canada server? The price online shows the Canada server is more cheaper than the Australia east server but I am concern about the speed cause Canada is far from NZ. What would be the best location for my cloud sql database? (Price, speed, location, etc...). Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Where users of your database are located?

Comment: Hi, @alex Users of my database located New Zealand.

Comment: Access latency depends on physical location, the further away the resource is the slower it will be to access. You have to decide for yourself what is more important (price or performance).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how slow speed it will be if I choose the Canada server (more cheap)?

Comment: No idea. Try testing it.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is very broad and opinion-soliciting (and arguably documentation request, since you're asking about pricing), with no "right" answer. Often, people pick a region most central to their customers, but if you have a global app presence, that may not be as important to you. Just be aware that, should you split services across regions, there will be latency and bandwidth costs. All pricing is available online, and you can determine that yourself, along with services offered on a per-region basis.

Comment: @NateLiu, ping a server in New Zealand and another in Canada to see the latency difference. Light only travels so fast and 10K Km is a long way. But such high latency may be acceptable depending on your use case and SLA.